# Windows 10 not responding after plugging docking station via USB-C

Tags: windows-10, freeze, asus-laptop, docking-station, zenbook

Windows does not display any image when plugging docking station and system freezes. When I plug USB-C cable monitor screen recognises the cable is plugged in but display stays black and unplugging leaves laptop not responding.

My docking station works normally with another laptop. It is connected via USB-C to two external Dell monitors. The laptop I am using is an ASUS ZenBook 14".

The screen only appears when I restart system with the docking station connected before.

I uninstalled the graphics card drivers and installed them again, uninstalled AMD Catalyst. Nothing helps.

My setup:
AMD Ryzen5 4500U with Radeon Graphics

Any clues how to solve or troubleshoot?

[Device Manager]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNr1I.png

Comment: You are 100% sure your device supports Type-C (DP Alt mode)?  I assume it's DisplayPort since that is the most common, it could be HDMI Alt Mode, and I would still have my question.